# dx Shader Model 3.0 break, continue, and loop attributes not recognized

Tags: directx, hlsl, directx9

I've been stuck on this problem for just too long. Long story short, the compiler returns "syntax error: unexpected token" for break, continue, [loop], [unroll] and pretty much every other attribute.

I am using DirectX SDK June 2010 on Windows 10, and compiling shaders for Source Engine 2013.

Microsoft Docs says these statements should be supported for pixel shader 3.0, so I absolutely have no idea what's wrong.

The entire code can be found here:

```
#include "common_vertexlitgeneric_dx9.h"

// front sampler and back samplers are used to calculate ray starting and ending points and direction. 

sampler2D frontSampler : register(s0);
sampler2D backSampler  : register(s1);
sampler3D volSampler   : register(s2);

const float3 nPasses   : register(c0);
const float3 nAlphaCorrection : register(c1);
const float3 nClip             : register(c2);




struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 FragPos                      : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 vPos                         : TEXCOORD1;

};


float4 raymarch(float4 p) 
    {

    float2 texC = p.xy /= p.w;
    texC.x =  0.5f*texC.x + 0.5f; 
    texC.y = -0.5f*texC.y + 0.5f;

    float3 front = tex2D(frontSampler, texC ).xyz;
    float3 back = tex2D(backSampler,texC).xyz;

    float3 dir = normalize(back - front);
    float4 pos = float4(front, 0);

    float4 dst = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    float4 src = 0;

    float value = 0;

    float3 Step = dir * (1/nPasses.x);

    // loop doesn't work, nor does unroll in this step 
    // if loop then syntax error unexpected token 'for'
    // if unroll then undeclared identifier 'unroll'

    [loop]
    for(int i = 0; i < nPasses.x; i++)
    {       

            pos.w = 0;
            value = tex3Dlod(volSampler, pos).r;

            src = (float4)value;

            src.x = src.x * 2 * step(pos.z, nClip.x); 
            src.y = pow(src.y*2,2)* step(pos.z, nClip.x); 
            src.z = pow(src.z*2,2)* step(pos.z, nClip.x); 
            src.a = src.a * step(pos.z, nClip.x); 


            src.a *= nAlphaCorrection.x; //reduce the alpha to have a more transparent result 

            //Front to back blending
            // dst.rgb = dst.rgb + (1 - dst.a) * src.a * src.rgb
            // dst.a   = dst.a   + (1 - dst.a) * src.a     
            src.rgb *= src.a;
            dst = (1.0f - dst.a)*src + dst;     

            //break from the loop when alpha gets high enough
            if (dst.a > 1.0f)

                break;


            //advance the current position

            //break if the position is greater than <1, 1, 1>
            if (pos.x > 1.0f | pos.y > 1.0f | pos.z > 1.0f) 


                continue;

            pos.xyz += Step;


    }

    return dst;

}



float4 main( PS_INPUT i ) : COLOR
{


    return FinalOutput( raymarch(i.vPos).rgba, 0, PIXEL_FOG_TYPE_NONE, TONEMAP_SCALE_LINEAR ); 
}
```

Comment: What is the command-line you are using to build this shader?

Comment: I'm using shadercompile.exe which passes down these flags to fxc.exe "fxc.exe /DTOTALSHADERCOMBOS=1 /DCENTROIDMASK=0 /DNUMDYNAMICCOMBOS=1 /DFFLAGS=0x0 /DSHADERCOMBO=0 /Dmain=main /Emain /Tps_3_0 /DSHADER_MODEL_PS_3_0=1 /nologo /Foshader.o"

Comment: Can you figure out exactly where ``fx.exe`` is located that you are invoking?